# How to stop a setInterval function on discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've been wanting to add a feature to my script, which can enable me to stop the setInterval function through a simple command, but the real problem is that I do not know how to do it.

```js
client.on('message', async (message) => {
 if (message.author.username === 'username')
  if (message.content === '*shiba inu pupper') {
   const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment('shiba doggo');

   setInterval(() => {
    message.channel.send(attachment);
   }, 20000);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

**Ex: Your interval function:**

```
let intervalFunc = setInterval(() => {
   // code .....
}, 20000);
```

**After that When you want to stop the interval time, use the below function:**

```
clearInterval(intervalFunc);
```

***Above function will clear your interval time***

Answer (score 2):

add my_interval global variable in your js file :

```
var my_interval;
```

then:

```js
client.on('message', async (message) => {
 if (message.author.username === 'username')
  if (message.content === '*shiba inu pupper') {
   const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment('shiba doggo');

   my_interval = setInterval(() => {
    message.channel.send(attachment);
   }, 20000);
  }
});
```

and whenever you went to stop that interval just call:

```
clearInterval(my_interval);
```